# Combine several pbix models into a single repository

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a collection of .pbix models that follow a similar structure, ie, have the same tables and relationships.

It is too complex to combine them all into a single .pbix.

Is there a way to upload all these tables into a single repository, like PBI Service dataflows or a data warehouse, or something similar.

And then get the data back to PBI Desktop and perform DAX calculations, visualizations and report.

Any suggestions/ ideas?

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: You can use dataflows for shared data tables, but I think for modeling the only option is to create a giant master data model, at least until such a time as it's possible to connect to multiple Power BI data models simultaneously. It's quite a frustrating predicament.

Comment: I have a folder with a lot of XML files, they have the same structure, so I use Power Query to import all from that folder and do the data transformation. But it gets too heavy when I include DAX and visuals, etc. Therefore, I need a tool to load all the tables to a database and then connect Power BI to it. That's the idea...

Comment: Your master file doesn't need to have any visuals, just your tables, relationships, and measures.

Comment: Thanks @AlexisOlson I'll check it!

Answer (score 1):

You can publish them to Power BI Service, and then create separate reports, but using these published datasets as a data source.

See [Connect to datasets in the Power BI service from Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-report-lifecycle-datasets).

After publishing your "model" reports to Power BI Online, start making a new blank report, but instead of getting the data from files/databases/etc., choose `Power BI service` as a data source and select the previously published dataset. After that, you can publish your report the same way, but in this case you can share one dataset (your model) between multiple reports.

Comment: @Adrey Nikolov, thanks for helping, but I can only import one dataset at a time from PBI service. Furthermore, can't edit the data model or add calculated columns/tables in that scenario.